# Как нарисовать несколько полигонов на Яндекс-картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Нужно, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку "Начать рисование" можно было нарисовать какое-то количество полигонов. А прекратить рисование после нажатия на другую кнопку. Но если с первой частью я справился, то со второй не могу.

Вот мой код:

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&amp;lang=ru-RU"></script>
        <script>
            ymaps.ready(function(){
            var map, center, zoom;
        var objectManager;
        var myPolygon;
        var coords = [];

            var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                    center: [ymaps.geolocation.latitude, ymaps.geolocation.longitude],
                    zoom: 10,
                    behaviors: ["default", "scrollZoom"],
                    type : 'yandex#map'
                });

            document.getElementById("btnStartDraw").addEventListener('click', createPolygon, false);
            document.getElementById("btnStopDraw").addEventListener('click', stopPolygon, false);

        function createPolygon() {
                 myPolygon = new ymaps.Polygon([], {}, {
                    editorDrawingCursor: "crosshair",
                    fillColor: '#00FF00',
                    strokeColor: '#0000FF',
                    strokeWidth: 3
                });
                map.geoObjects.add(myPolygon);

                var stateMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(myPolygon.editor.state);
                stateMonitor.add("drawing", function (newValue) {
                    myPolygon.options.set("strokeColor", newValue ? '#FF0000' : '#0000FF');
                });

               myPolygon.editor.startDrawing();
                myPolygon.editor.events.add("drawingstop", function (e) {
                    getCoords(myPolygon.geometry.getCoordinates());
                });
        };
        function getCoords(coordsArr) {
            coords.push(coordsArr);
            var stateMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(myPolygon.editor.state);
            if (!stateMonitor.drawing) createPolygon();
        };

        function removePolygon() {
            map.geoObjects.remove(myPolygon);
        };

        function stopPolygon() {
                myPolygon.editor.stopDrawing();

        };


        });
        </script>
        <div id="map" class="map" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;">
            <button id="btnStartDraw">Начать рисовать</button>
            <button id="btnStopDraw" > Остановить рисование</button>

    </div>
```

[Пример кода на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coldalmaty/eq2r46wL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Решение!
создал дополнительную переменную `var isDraw = true;`
В функции createPolygon

```
    myPolygon.editor.events.add("drawingstop", function (e) {          
    isDraw ? getCoords(myPolygon.geometry.getCoordinates()) : myPolygon.editor.stopDrawing();
    });
```

соответственно при нажатии на кнопку отмены рисования меняем значение переменной с `true` на `false`.